# Brocade alishow merge two consecutive lines awk sed

Tags: sed, awk

How would like to join two lines usung awk or sed?

For example, I have data like below:

```
abcd
12:12:12:12:12:12:12:12
efgh001_01
45:45:45:45:45:45:45:45
ijkl7464746
78:78:78:78:78:78:78:78
```

and I need output like below:

```
abcd 12:12:12:12:12:12:12:12
efgh001_01 45:45:45:45:45:45:45:45
ijkl7464746 78:78:78:78:78:78:78:78
```

Running this almost works, but I need the space or tab:

```
awk '!(NR%2){print$0p}{p=$0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
awk '(NR % 2 == 0) {print p, $0} {p = $0}'
```

Comment: or `awk '!(NR%2){print $0" "p}{p=$0}'`

Comment: So close... cat ali | awk '(NR % 2 == 0) {print p, $0} {p = $0}'
        AIT001  10:00:00:00:c9:82:4c:f2         AIT004  21:00:00:e0:8b:91:35:14
        AIXNIM_A                        10:00:00:00:c9:31:3a:ef
        AMS1000_CTL1_B                  50:06:0e:80:10:09:c5:35
        AMS2500PROD_CL0A_EXTERNAL                       50:06:0e:80:10:0a:d6:a0
        AMS2500PROD_CL1A_EXTERNAL                       50:06:0e:80:10:0a:d6:a8
        C1B01   21:00:00:09:6b:36:d0:7a         C1B02   21:00:00:09:6b:36:ba:c8
        C1B04   21:00:00:09:6b:36:ba:ea

Comment: I think the problem I am having is when I run alishow on my switches I get the following:         AIT001  10:00:00:00:c9:82:4c:f2
        AIT004  21:00:00:e0:8b:91:35:14
        AIXNIM_A
                10:00:00:00:c9:31:3a:ef
If I do an od -a on the file, I see a combination of :

Comment: 0000000   sp  ht   A   I   T   0   0   1  ht   1   0   :   0   0   :   0
0000020    0   :   0   0   :   c   9   :   8   2   :   4   c   :   f   2
0000040   lf  sp  ht   A   I   T   0   0   4  ht   2   1   :   0   0   :
0000060    0   0   :   e   0   :   8   b   :   9   1   :   3   5   :   1
0000100    4  lf  sp  ht   A   I   X   N   I   M   _   A  ht  lf  ht  ht
0000120    1   0   :   0   0   :   0   0   :   0   0   :   c   9   :   3
0000140    1   :   3   a   :   e   f  lf  sp  ht

Comment: @LanOps: please don't use comments to post long parts of text files, they become completely unreadable.

Comment: Because I am new, there is no way for me to post replies other than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

With sed you can do that as follows:

```
sed -n 'N;s/\n/ /p' file
```

where:

- `N` reads next line
- `s` replaces the new line character with a space to join both lines properly
- `p` prints the result

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' file
```

or this:

```
paste -sd' \n' file
```